# Validate name1 and name 2 to connection,prov

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I want to validate two named connections and their connection status and the `prov id` value from a given text file with Python/Robot Framework. Below is a sample from the text file `Test.txt`

> name..........: uhn3
> connection....: Connected (1)
> prov id.......: <[1] id:17/IPv6:240bc0ea01e1554e:a01000000000002/128:5551>
> connection....: Connected (1)
> prov id.......: <[2] id:17/IPv6:240bc0ea01e1554e:a01000000000002/128:5552>
> connection....: Connected (1)
> name..........: uhn3k
> connection....: Connected (145)
> prov id.......: <[3] id:16/IPv6:240bc0ea01e1554e:a01000000000001/128:5551>
> connection....: Connected (1)
> prov id.......: <[4] id:16/IPv6:240bc0ea01e1554e:a01000000000001/128:5552>
> connection....: Connected (1)
> *

and this is the Robot script I have used.

```
*** Variables ***
@{application_reqfields}  name  connection  prov id
    
*** Test Case ***
Login SG and check the status
    ${Cmd_Output}=  Get File  Test.txt
    log to console  ${Cmd_Output}
    ${retVal}=  application_validation   ${Cmd_Output}      
    ${application_reqfields}
    log to console  ${retVal}
    
*** Keywords ***
application_validation
    [Arguments]     ${output}   ${reqFields}
    &{retVal}=  Create Dictionary
    FOR     ${field}     IN      @{reqFields}
        @{match}=  Get Regexp Matches   ${output}     .*${field}\\.*\\:\\s*(\\w+)  1
        set to dictionary   ${retVal}   ${field}    ${match}
    END
    [return]  ${retVal}
```

The keyword `application_validation` passes and the output looks like

> { 'name': ['uhn3', 'uhn3k'], 'connection': ['Connected', 'Connected', 'Connected', 'Connected', 'Connected'], 'prov id': [] }

I'd need to retrieve the name and related connection status for that connection from the returned value.

Comment: Could you provide the issue you are having? Are you looking to get the value after the colon or the whole string from ``name..........: uhn3`` or something else?

Comment: I am expecting output below name connection is connected or not,like that Prov id -connection is connected or not..

Comment: @Morkkis I am expecting output below name connection is connected or not,like that Prov id -connection is connected or not.

Comment: The question is still missing the question, or issue you are having - What is being output and why the output is not suitable for you. Consider checking [Guide on Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: @Morkkis I got output like .{'name': ['uhn3', 'uhn3k'], 'connection': ['Connected', 'Connected', 'Connected', 'Conne
cted', 'Connected'], 'prov id': []}
Login SG and check the status                                         | PASS |    <br> I want to retrieve connection state WRT name ,provId

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have two issues in the script, one is related to not being able to access the correct dictionary value for validation and another is that there is the `prov id` value which is returned as an empty list.

### General Use of Get Regexp Matches

The output you are receiving is actually described in the [String Library documentation](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Get%20Regexp%20Matches) for keyword `Get Regexp Matches`. There it is stated that the keyword will return *a list of **all** non-overlapping matches*. This means that the output you are receiving is as expected.

You can access dictionary values in Robot Framework simply by using

```
${VALUE}=    Set Variable    ${DICT[key]}
```

Because you are having the values behind the keys as lists, you'll need to first get the list out of the dictionary and then access the index in the list you wish to open.

```
${name1}=    Get From List    ${retVal["name"]}    0
```

[Get From List is from Collections library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Get%20From%20List). But of course this will only return the name and not anything related to it.

Additionally your issue with the `prov id` is simply due to your regexp call not considering the extra characters in the value. If you change the regexp to consider those instead of simply expecting whitespace it will work fine. This regexp seems to work fine.

```
${field}\.*\:\s(.*\w+)
```

### Maintaining Item Relation

In order to maintain the relation between items so that the `name` can be attached to the corresponding entries of `prov id`/`connection` you would need to have a set rule on how the entities work here, consider for example

> A `name` field starts a new entity, each `connection`/`prov id` is related to the `name` above it.

Or

> Only 3 `connection` fields may exist for `name`

Once you have figured that out, you can use following script to capture each field separately and then build from there. I'm assuming that whatever is under the specific `name` will be assigned to that field, regardless how many entries there are.

```
application_validation
    [Arguments]     ${output}   ${reqFields}
    &{retVal}=  Create Dictionary
    @{entities}=  Split String    ${output}    name  # Splitting the string on name field
    ${removed}=  Remove From List    ${entities}    0  # Removing empty item on index 0
    FOR  ${item}    IN   @{entities}    # Iterating to get data based on names
        @{name}=    Get Regexp Matches    ${item}    ^\\.*\\:\\s(?P<name>\\w+)    name  # Expecting only single name but the keyword will return a list anyway
        @{connections}=    Get Regexp Matches    ${item}    connection\\.*\\:\\s*(?P<conn>\\w+)  conn
        @{provs}=  Get Regexp Matches    ${item}    prov id\\.*\\:\\s*(?P<prov>.*\\w+)  prov

        # Let's assign the connection status to correct prov id
        &{tempdict}=    Create Dictionary
        FOR    ${conn}  ${prov}    IN ZIP    @{connections}  @{provs}
            Set to Dictionary    ${tempdict}    ${prov}=${conn}
        END
        # Then we need to create an output for each name/value entity
        Set to Dictionary    ${retVal}    ${name}[0]=${tempdict}
    END
    [Return]    ${retVal}
```

The above script will provide you with a dictionary with nested dictionary for each `name` where the inner dictionary contains `prov id` as a key and `connection` as the value. For example the `uhn3` from your example would be returned as

```
&{retVal}= { "uhn3": {"<[1] id:17/IPv6:240bc0ea01e1554e:a01000000000002/128:5551>": "connected", "<[2] id:17/IPv6:240bc0ea01e1554e:a01000000000002/128:5552>": "connected" }
```

The weakness of this script will however be if there is a possibility of different number of `connection` and `prov id` fields, there will be index error so you'll have to adjust accordingly.

Calling the values from the dictionary can be done by first getting the outer dictionary

```
FOR    ${name}    IN     @{retVal.keys()}
    Log    ${name}
    FOR    ${conn}    IN   @{name.keys()}
        Log    ${conn}: ${name[${conn}]}
    END
END
```

Comment: Thanks,Morkkis for your valuable and nice input.I tried ,but still not able to validate this name-connection prov id -connection is connetced or not
Output:- {'name': ['uhn3', 'uhn3k'], 'connection': ['Connected (1', '
Connected (1', 'Connected (1', 'Connected (145', 'Connected (1', 'Connected (1'], 'prov id': ['<[1] id:17/<IPv6:240bc002/128>:5551'
, '<[2] id:17/<IPv6:240b002/128>:5552', '<[3] id:16/<IPv6:240bc1/128>:5551', '<[4] id:16/<IPv6:240bc0ea0
1e1554001/128>:5552']}
Suppose I retrieve the first name(uhn3) ,how can i know wrt to this name connection/prov id connection is connected.

Comment: ,I am not able to filter wrt to name- connection of prov id that its connected or not .

Comment: @Sudhanshu To maintain the item relation between ``name`` and ``connection``/``prov id`` you'd need to have a rule which dictates how many occurrences of each key is there possibly existing or something like "each ``name`` starts new entity" - Only then you can make a script to follow that rule. If there is one, you have not presented such in the question.

Comment: Thanks @Morkkis,here **name** is **Unique**,name can be multiple/single prov/id and  having **Name associated with provID** connection  I have to validate

Comment: I have adjusted my answer accordingly. @Sudhanshu

Comment: 1:- '@{entities}=  Remove From List    @{lines}    0 ' # **Lines variable is not there**,'Set to Dictionary    &{retVal}    ${name}[0]=${tempdict}'  # **Keyword 'Collections.Set To Dictionary' got positional argument after named arguments**      A ton of thanks for your valuable input,I am new in this coding

Comment: My mistake, should have been ``${entities}=  Remove From List  ${lines}  0`` instead - Fixing the answer once more. You can see the documentation in the [Collections Library](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Remove%20From%20List). Also same thing for the ``Set to Dictionary`` - Should have used $ instead of &.

Comment: ${lines} variable we are not defined any where,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235128/discussion-between-sudhanshu-and-morkkis).

Comment: Thanks Morkkis,But still not able to fetch any data in name,connection,prov id:-  
**14:39:09.050 INFO @{name} = [ ]**  **14:39:09.050 INFO @{connections} = [ ]**  **14:39:09.050 INFO @{provs} = [ ]**    **KEYWORD Collections . Set To Dictionary ${retVal}, ${name}[0]=${tempdict}
Documentation: 
Adds the given key_value_pairs and items to the dictionary.

Start / End / Elapsed: 20210721 14:39:09.050 / 20210721 14:39:09.050 / 00:00:00.000
14:39:09.050 **FAIL List '${name}' has no item in index 0.**

Comment: I think issue on  **remove from list ** line

Comment: I just realised my mistake - Sorry for that. The ``Remove From List`` keyword returns the removed value and not the original list in its changed form - Which is why we simply take the returned value and forget it. This way we can use the ``@{entities}`` without the unnecessary empty value normally. Hope this is now cleared for you.